# What is the best way to do a redirect from / with ASP MVC3 Routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I currently have the following route set up:

```
    context.MapRoute("Root", "", new
    {
        controller = "Server",
        action = "FavoritesList",
        id = "00C"
    }
    );
```

However I would like to change this so the default goes to the following:

```
/F00C/Home-About#/C01C/Overview
```

I realize this doesn't map to controllers and actions but is there a way I can just do an **internal redirect** with the MapRoute to a another href.

Comment: What do you mean by *default goes to*? What *default*?

Comment: I mean where a user goes to when he just gives the web address with nothing after the ".com" such as www.stackoverflow.com. If a user does not enter anything after the www.abcde.com then I would like him to be sent to the www.abcde.com/F00C/Home-About#/C01C/Overview page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you would like your default page to be that meaning that if someone hits your root / you would like them to be redirected to /F00C/Home-About#/C01C/Overview, then simply assuming you have these routes in global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultRedirect", // Route name
    string.Empty, // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirect" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Homepage",
    "F00C/Home-About",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

You can do this in your HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    return Redirect("~/F00C/Home-About#/C01C/Overview");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to say

You can also just configure a redirect in IIS itself if that is more to your liking, but this way it is part of the application.